# Can Windows call the WinMain function in a Static Library C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static-libraries, .lib

I have created a Static library which contains a WinMain() function that has to be called. I'm searching for some way to make windows call this function.

The reason is to have a solution without a Main Function, in which the user just inherit and fill some classes, and if he hits the play button, the solution runs.

Also, if you think my approach is not the best, tell me how you will afford this.

Comment: That should "just work".  The linker will search for functions named "WinMain" (decorated) in both object files and static libraries passed to it.  Show what you tried and what errors you got.

Comment: Why should a static `library` have a `main`? :S.. What happens when I link it with my program that already has a main? In GCC, you can have a `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` but I think it's for dynamic libs only. Not too sure.

Comment: @Brandon That's how the CRT libraries work, for example, in order to "inject" their initialization code before *they* call the user-defined `main`.

Comment: @Brandon: Many platforms/frameworks work that way, the entry point is in framework code and all the user code is event-driven.  In fact in C++ the "main()" or "WinMain()"
function is not even the true entry point, the toolchain arranges for its startup code which constructs global objects to run first.

Comment: @BenVoigt The solution compiles when I hit Run, but then says that it didn't find the .exe. I associate this to the WinMain entry point but maybe it is something different (?)

Comment: A solution is just a container for projects.  You will need a static library project and an executable project which includes (links with) the static library.  A static library cannot be executed on its own... plus you would be missing the pieces that are supposed to be filled in by the user.

Comment: You might want to look at how other frameworks do this, Hans has explained Microsoft's MFC one pretty well here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6871836/103167  And here is a very simplified example of how the code could look: http://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/mfc-application-winmain().php

Answer (score 0):

You could add `#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:fn")` to modify the entry function. Also, you could refer to [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=vs-2019)